# TinyMCE for rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, tinymce, static-pages

in show page, i will convert string into hash,

form.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 20, :cols => 120 %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('textarea').tinymce({
  theme: 'advanced'
});
});
</script>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p>
<%= @page.content %>
</p>
<p>
<%= link_to "Edit", editcontent_path(@page), :class => "abutton" %> |
<%= link_to "Destroy", destroycontent_path(@page), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> |
<%= link_to "View All", admins_view_content_path %>
</p>
```

but my page following, code not convert

[image: code not convert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used tinymce , but as per documentation what I understand is

If you want to add content to editor pass that to the text area

```
<%= text_area_tag :editor, @page.content , :class => "tinymce", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>

# you can pass configuration option to tinymce here
<%= tinymce %>
```

In Show page

```
<p>
<%= @page.content.html_safe %> #Apply html_safe function to interpret string as html
</p>
```

This works for me.

Comment: shift the @page.content from <%= tinymce %> to text_area_tag check my answer, this error occurs when you pass <%= tinymce %> ,a string argument it needs a Hash of configuraion options here.

Comment: @anonymousxxx, Use html_safe helper to convert the string content to html display. check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Optionally raw(@page.content) also works